# Having 0x80004005 in Workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow

I'm having the 0x80004005 error in a SharePoint Workflow and can't really figure out where to start looking

Exception

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Det går inte att slutföra åtgärden.  Försök igen. 
---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Det går inte att slutföra åtgärden.  
     Försök igen.<nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>    

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetSecurityInfo(String bstrUrl, String bstrObjUrl, Guid& pguidScopeId, UInt64& pEffectivePermMask, Boolean& pbHasUniquePerm, String& pbstrPermUrl)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetSecurityInfo(String bstrUrl, String bstrObjUrl, Guid& pguidScopeId, UInt64& pEffectivePermMask, Boolean& pbHasUniquePerm, String& pbstrPermUrl)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetSecurityInfo(String bstrUrl, String bstrObjUrl, Guid& pguidScopeId, UInt64& pEffectivePermMask, Boolean& pbHasUniquePerm, String& pbstrPermUrl)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.InitSecurity()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.get_SecurableObjectImpl()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(Boolean copyRoleAssignments, Boolean clearSubscopes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOETaskService.CommitTask(Transaction txn, Object[] transData)
```

- Det går inte att slutföra åtgärden.  Försök igen. = Cannot perform the operation, please try again

Comment: This is due to the process not being able to use SharePoint dll, solution here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2012/08/13/404-error-on-a-sharepoint-site-comexception-0x80004005-the-operation-cannot-be-completed-successfully.aspx

Comment: @RobertLindgren It could have been but I already tried that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was created since the workflow was created for SharePoint 2010 SP1 and my setup was using SP2. Reinstalling SharePoint was the solution